# Detect when Object Tag loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object-tag

How can I detect when a object tag loads?
I am using the following script.

```
var object = $("<object></object>"); 
object.attr("data", "page.html");
$("body").append(object);               
object.onload = function(){ // Doesn't work
    console.log("Loaded");
};
```

And I don't want to use iframes.

Comment: http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/executing-javascript-when-the-swf-has-finished-loading/

Comment: @Donal What if the content is actually an html file?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25653689/379855 below, should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

```
var object = $("<object></object>"); 
object.attr("data", "man.swf");
$("body").append(object);               
object.load("ajax/test.html",function(){ // Doesn't work
    console.log("Loaded");
});
```

You are missing "ajax/test.html"

This should work.

Comment: What ?? The object tag is in the html file. I want to detect whenever it has fully loaded.